# Is there any function or tool (free) to auto complete any .Net type name to fully qualified one?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm using VB.NET with Visual Studio 2010. Is there any function or tool to auto complete any .Net type name to fully qualified one?

I mean a tool/function that actually **changing the source code** from short hand to fully qualified name like following:

From `String` to `System.String`

From `Process.Start` to this `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`

**UPDATE:**

> Thanks for ReSharper suggestion. But
>   I'm not prepared to buy it or award
>   bounty for a commercial product
>   suggestion. **Sorry about that**. I should
>   make my question clear about that
>   requirement. I already tried ReSharper
>   before asking this question.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It makes the code unreadable.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Normally I will print out any problematic parts of code. And fully qualified names are helpful for me

Comment: I could see where this would help when there are potential namespace collisions. `Rectangle` is the one that comes to mind for me the most, it seems every library has one.

Comment: @Dee Jay, before your edit you didn't ask about a *free* tool. R# does a lot for productivity and it IMHO really worth its money; if you use it for an open-source project you may try and apply for a free opensource usage license.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a macro that works fine for C# code.

When I tested it on a VB .Net project it didn't work for types in assembly references. Seems like the project code model for VB.Net excludes external types.

I include the code here anyway. Maybe someone else knows how to do it for VB

---

First we need a function that finds the current context

```
Private Function FindCodeElement(ByVal caretPosition As TextPoint, ByVal elems As CodeElements) As CodeElement
    If elems Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Return elems.Cast(Of CodeElement) _
                .Where(Function(x) x.StartPoint.LessThan(caretPosition) AndAlso _
                                   x.EndPoint.GreaterThan(caretPosition)) _
                .Select(Function(x) If(FindCodeElement(caretPosition, GetMembers(x)), x)) _
                .FirstOrDefault()
End Function
```

We also need a function that create all candidate names based on using/import statements

```
Private Sub FindAllCandidates(ByVal elem As Object, ByVal className As String)
    If TypeOf elem Is CodeFunction Then
        FindAllCandidates(CType(elem, CodeFunction).Parent, className)
    ElseIf TypeOf elem Is CodeClass Then
        mCandidates.Add(CType(elem, CodeClass).FullName & "." & className)
        FindAllCandidates(CType(elem, CodeClass).Parent, className)
    ElseIf TypeOf elem Is CodeStruct Then
        mCandidates.Add(CType(elem, CodeStruct).FullName & "." & className)
        FindAllCandidates(CType(elem, CodeStruct).Parent, className)
    ElseIf TypeOf elem Is CodeNamespace Then
        mCandidates.Add(CType(elem, CodeNamespace).FullName & "." & className)
        For Each ns As String In CType(elem, CodeNamespace).Members.OfType(Of CodeImport) _
                                                                   .Select(Function(x) x.Namespace)
            mCandidates.Add(ns & "." & className)
        Next
        FindAllCandidates(CType(elem, CodeNamespace).Parent, className)
    ElseIf TypeOf elem Is FileCodeModel Then
        For Each ns As String In CType(elem, FileCodeModel).CodeElements.OfType(Of CodeImport) _
                                                                        .Select(Function(x) x.Namespace)
            mCandidates.Add(ns & "." & className)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

And then a function that loops all available items to find one of the candidates

```
Private Function FindClassInCodeElements(ByVal elems As CodeElements) As CodeElement
    If elems Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    For Each elem As CodeElement In elems
        If IsClassType(elem) Then
            If mCandidates.Contains(elem.FullName) Then Return elem
        ElseIf TypeOf elem Is CodeNamespace Then
            For Each candidate As String In mCandidates
                If candidate.StartsWith(elem.FullName) Then
                    Dim found As CodeElement = FindClassInCodeElements(GetMembers(elem))
                    If found IsNot Nothing Then Return found
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Two small helper functions

```
Private Function IsClassType(ByVal elem As CodeElement) As Boolean
    Return TypeOf elem Is CodeClass OrElse TypeOf elem Is CodeStruct OrElse TypeOf elem Is CodeInterface
End Function

Private Function GetMembers(ByVal elem As CodeElement) As CodeElements
    If TypeOf elem Is CodeClass Then
        Return CType(elem, CodeClass).Members
    ElseIf TypeOf elem Is CodeNamespace Then
        Return CType(elem, CodeNamespace).Members
    ElseIf TypeOf elem Is CodeStruct Then
        Return CType(elem, CodeStruct).Members
    ElseIf TypeOf elem Is CodeInterface Then
        Return CType(elem, CodeInterface).Members
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

And then we can write the main function which you can alter depending on how you want to use it.

```
Dim mCandidates As New HashSet(Of String)

Sub ExpandFullNameOfSelection()
    Dim selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection(), EnvDTE.TextSelection)
    ' Assume type is selected
    Dim className As String = selection.Text

    ' Find current context
    Dim currentFunction As CodeElement = FindCodeElement(selection.ActivePoint, DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements)

    mCandidates.Clear()
    FindAllCandidates(currentFunction, className)

    Dim classType As CodeElement = DTE.Solution.Projects.Cast(Of Project) _
                                                        .Where(Function(x) x.CodeModel IsNot Nothing) _
                                                        .Select(Function(x) FindClassInCodeElements(x.CodeModel.CodeElements)) _
                                                        .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x IsNot Nothing)
    If classType IsNot Nothing Then
        selection.Text = classType.FullName ' replace with full name
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Im trying to implement this, and I'm getting an error: Public member 'Cast' on type 'CNamespaceCollection' not found at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack)

Comment: The error happens at Runtime, compile time is happy, so I suspect there needs to be an additional exclusion in the Where -- ?

Comment: @user230910, the error indicates you use late binding which does not work with extension methods. Enable option explicit, strict and infer.

Answer (score 13):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) is capable of doing this.

Although Resharper is not free, it is absolutely worth buying. Once started using Resharper, you will not be able to proceed without it.

Showing the step by step below, because it is not quite trivial how to do this:

1. Download and install Resharper.
2. Open VS and go to menu `Rehsarper` => `Options` => `Languages` => `C#` => `Namespace Import`. Select `Use fully qualified names`. By default `Insert using directives when necessary` is selected.

   [image]

   From now on, whenever you use `Alt+Enter` to resolve namespace, Resharper will resolve fully qualified one.
3. Go to `Rehsarper` => `Options` => `Tools` => `Code cleanup`. Hit `Add` button to add new Cleanup profile. Give a name to the new profile, e.g. `Namespaces Reformat`. Check `Optimizing using directives` checkbox.
   [image]
4. Right click on the project and select `Cleanup Code...`, or use shortcut `Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C`. Select previously created profile and hit `Run` button.

   [image]

---

Test

Original code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Result code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that the instructions in the JetBrains help are not as precise as yours, and +1 for that. Basically my point was just that some credit for being the first to suggest this functionality in this specific tool would have been nice. In any way, thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

[JetBrains' ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) [can do this via the "Code Cleanup" function](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Usage_Scenarios__Shortening_Qualified_References.html), along with many other code changes (such as explicit type usage instead of `var` etc.).

Note that I'm not affiliated, but a big fan of R#.