# Collect a list of user classes in a project using EnvDTE

Tags: c#, t4, envdte

I am having a problem creating a way to list all the classes in my project using `EnvDTE` for templating interfaces using T4 (based on naming conventions), and none of the documentation out there seems to describe how to do it.  I started out with:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ Assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#
    var env = (DTE)((IServiceProvider)this.Host)
        .GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
```

... and then I started going sideways.  I am able to identify my project, but I am not able to collect the classes in the project that I want to filter into a flat list for creating interfaces for.

How can I do this?  I just want the classes in my project.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Visual Studio. If so, have you looked at Roslyn at all?

Comment: Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6572941/157224 about finding classes with DTE

Comment: @adrianm, this looks like it might be what I'm looking for (once I translate to c#)... I will try this in the morning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are using T4 i would suggest you check out the [tangible T4 Editor](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html). In their gallery is a free reusable Template "tangible Visual Studio Automation Helper". With this template you can easily find Code Classes etc. (See my answer to this post [Design Time Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134016/design-time-reflection/14402269#14402269)).

If you want to do it on your own you should continue like this:

```
    var project = env.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject;
foreach(EnvDTE.CodeElement element in project.CodeModel.CodeElements)
{
    if (element.Kind == EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass)
    {
        var myClass = (EnvDTE.CodeClass)element;
        // do stuff with that class here
    }
}
```

I removed the recursion that would be necessary. A CodeElement can contain other CodeElements. But this way it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to much about T4 templates, but can you use `Reflection` in one to get your class's

Eg:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ Assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ Import Namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#

    var list = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass);
```

Comment: Reflection, unfortunately, gets all boogered up when trying to self-reflect.  It caches data and does not necessarily update when you change code.

Comment: Is that only in a T4 template , beacuse I have never seen that issue before