# How can I get the list of declared in Solution/Project types in design time?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

We need to generate a set of interfaces and classes putting them in different projects of the solution depending on the already declared types.

I think [T4 Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) can suffice. If not, then I will create Visual Studio AddIn /VSPackage.
But I have know idea how to get the list of available types.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal once you have this?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski We want to reduce manual typing for boilerplate code.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski, offtopic: What does abbreviation DTE mean here?

Comment: "Design Time Extensibility"...a name that doesn't really have a huge or deep meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only public API is to use the CodeModel/EnvDTE APIs. At a high level, you want to get a DTE [Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.codemodel.aspx) instance, and get it's CodeModel property. From there you can walk and get types. If you're already generating source, then you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14402548/972216). If T4 isn't what you want, then it's hard to give details.